# Poisson distribution where $\ \lambda,\ $ the average rate of events, varies with time or space?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

A Poisson distribution models tells us the number of times an event occurs in an interval of time or space, but $\ \lambda\ $ is a constant, so this rate is fixed.

What if the rate changes with time or space, e.g. instead of $X \sim Po(10),\ $ what if we had, for example, $X \sim Po(\ln(t+1))),\ t>0,\ t \text{ is time in minutes since math.se website's launch?}\ $

This could represent many other real-world things, but for this example let $X$ be the random variable: "number of questions asked each hour on math.se (e.g. in the first few years of the website's launch)".

Is is known how to do calculations like finding $P(1300\leq X\leq1400) $ in the first week of the website's launch?

[Note the I am just making up the numbers of course, but I have tried to do it in a way so that the probability is not obviously close to $1$ or $0$.]

I think maybe we would need to do some sort of [mean of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) or integral or double integral but I'm not sure what or how or if there is any literature on a $\ \lambda\ $ that varies.

Answer (score 1):

If the varying parameter at time $t$ is $\lambda(t)$ then the number between times $t_1$ and $t_2$ will be distributed $\mathrm{Po}(\mu)$ where $\mu = \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} \lambda(t) \, dt$.

Then the probability that this number is from $a$ through to $b$ is then $\sum\limits_{n=a}^b e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^n}{n!}$,

and if this calculation is too difficult then a normal approximation may be $\Phi\left(\dfrac{b+\frac12-\mu}{\sqrt{\mu}}\right)-\Phi\left(\dfrac{a-\frac12-\mu}{\sqrt{\mu}}\right)$ and you can drop the second term if $a=0$.

You will need to ensure consistency in the time units: your example mixes minutes and weeks.

Comment: It should be noted that this works only because of a special property of the Poisson distribution. This would not work in general for other distributions depending on a single parameter.